# Why did Kaikeyi send Lord Rama on Vanvas?

Tags: ramayana, history, rama, yashoda, kaikeyi

The most popular story is that Kaikeyi's maid poisoned her mind. Due to this, she sent Lord Rama on a Vanvas.

Although, I heard a different story in a *Katha* recently. The story goes like Lord Rama was to be coronated as the king. Although, he knew this was not his purpose of descent (of being an avatara). He shared this dilemma with Kaikeyi. Kaikeyi suggested the solution that she will send him on Vanvas. Rama said that she will become infamous for thousands of years to come. Although, Kaikeyi said that she was fine with that as long as she was born as his mother in the next birth too. Hence, Lord Rama was born as Lord Krishna, and Kaikeyi took rebirth as Yashoda.

Is there any version of the *Ramayana* that mentions this story?

Comment: You can read Valmiki Ramayana at [valmikiramayan.net](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/ayodhya_contents.htm). There are many loose ends in the story you heard. Rama was not aware of his avatara, [he thought himself to be a human](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga117/yuddhasans117.htm#Verse11). If your story were true, he could just speak to his own father or mother instead of Kaikeyi about his mission on earth and I'm sure something less strenuous could have worked out :-)

Comment: @sv.: Interesting points. Although, if you read Yoga Vashishtha, it clearly shows that Dashratha loved Rama too much to let him go. When Valkimi arrives and asks to take Rama away to fight some demons, Dashratha refuses. So, Rama could not have talked to his father. Regarding, whether Rama thought himself 'human', Rama was quite 'desolate' after his trip through the country, as mentioned in the Yoga Vashihstha again. Sage Vashishtha arrives and gives him 'knowledge'. There is a definite acknowledgement by the end of text that he was aware that he had reached the 'highest state'.

Comment: @SayNoToCensorship Even if he was an avatar he would still be human. If being human means not being a God, the Manu Smriti should be disregarded as Manu is human. I think the fact Manu is human is a major warning sign not to blindly trust the Manu Smriti, but that does not seem to click with people.

Answer (score 2):

Ramayana written by Sage Valmiki is the authentic version of Ramayana. Valmiki was given a boon by Lord Brahma that when he starts writing the Ramayana, he will know the past, present of the characters. He will automatically know the ideas and thoughts of the character even though they are not met with him. Hence Ramayana written by Valmiki is true and authentic version of Ramayana. He is not paralleled to anyone even he is Rama or Ravana. He wrote what happened exactly.

When we come to your question, Manthara, house maid who was residing with Kaikeyi since her birth was the reason for the brainwash of Kaikeyi.

Manthara spoke to Kaikeyi

> यदा हि रामः पृथिवीमवाप्स्यति |
>   ध्रुवं प्रणष्टो भरतो भविष्यति |
>   अतो हि संचिन्तय राज्यमात्मजे |
>   पर्स्य चैवाद्य विवासकारणम् ||
>
> When Rama gets the power of the kingdom Bharata will certainly gets ruined. Hence, think of a solution to get your son Bharata the kingdom and to send Rama, your enemy, to exile.

The version of story you heard might be a folklore. Many stories came into existence as such even though it is not mentioned in Valmiki Ramayana. You may read the full Ramayana [here](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/) with English translation.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but the core i.e. the translation is completely wrong (whoever has done it). I know Sanskrit and it translates thus: "O Kaikeyi!, you grief causes me a lot of grief too. Also, there is no doubt that because of the conflict in you mind, I am conflicted too"